Proving the analyticity of a complex function defined by contour integration
Define analytic to be continuously differentiable. The fact that all complex differentiable functions are analytic has not been proven.
Suppose we have a closed path s (continuous function) of bounded variation(s is not necessarily a smooth function). We then use the Riemann-Stieltjes integral to define a contour integral over the path s(I am using Conway as a reference). We have an open set G. For z belonging to G and the path lying in G:
$g(z)=\oint\limits_{s}\phi(z,w)dw$. The path integral is over s. Assume that φ is continuous (as a function from GxG to C) and it is analytic for each fixed w, ie, the function h(z)=φ(z,w) is analytic.
How do I prove g is analytic and therefore continuous? Do we need to assume G is bounded to prove it?
To prove continuity I feel that if we assume the boundedness of G then that would suffice but to prove analyticity I have no idea.
The function $\phi$ is defined as $\phi(z,w)=(f(z)-f(w))/(z-w)$ for $z\neq w$ and $f'(z)$ otherwise, where f is analytic

There is a standard proof using Morera's Theorem.
